# write a while, do-while, and a for loop converting miles to kilometers (they must all 3 print exactly the same)

Tags: java

Like the title suggests.  I wrote the code and it works perfect with the while loop.  But when i add in the other 2 loops they don't all 3 print.  I do not understand why the other 2 loops will not print but Java throws no red flags. So i assume the code is written good enough for it to accept but not correctly.  the code is as below

```
package thebrain;


import java.util.Scanner;

public class TheBrain {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter the starting mile: ");
    int start = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter the ending mile: ");
    int end = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println();

    while (start <= end){
        double km = start * 1.609;
        System.out.println("miles: " + (start) + ", " + 
                "kilometers: " + (km));
        start += 1;
    }
    System.out.println();

    do { 
        double km = start * 1.609;
        start += 1;
        System.out.println("miles: " + (start) + ", " + 
                "kilometers: " + (km));

    } while (start <= end);

    for (int s=start; s <= end; s++){
        double km = start * 1.609;
        System.out.println("miles: " + (s) + ", " + 
                "kilometers: " + (km));
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you're adding `+1` each iteration on your loop to `start`, so when you get to this line:

```
while (start <= end);
```

`start` is already higher than `end`, so, it never enters but once (`do-while` enters once always) but in the `for` loop, it never enters.

You could create an auxiliary variable:

```
int aux = start; //Do this after you've read start from the user input
```

On your loops you'll need to increment `aux` instead of `start`:

```
aux += 1; //You can also write it as aux++; (Which I prefer to use)
```

Then before the `do-while` restart `aux` to the `start` value

```
aux = start;
do {
    //Your code here
} while (...);
```

And the same before the `for` loop

---

Aside note, does your class compiles?

```
public class the brain {
```

Java doesn't accepts spaces between variables / class names. Please follow the [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html), class names should start with an UpperCamelCase.

Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo) might not be happening now, but could be related in future problems, be sure to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

By the time you get to the 2nd loop, start will already have exceeded end, so the conditions for the 2nd and 3rd loops will always be false.

Try this:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter the starting mile: ");
int start = keyboard.nextInt();
System.out.print("Enter the ending mile: ");
int end = keyboard.nextInt();
System.out.println();

int wstart = start; //working variable;

while (wstart <= end){
    double km = start * 1.609;
    System.out.println("miles: " + (wstart) + ", " + 
            "kilometers: " + (km));
    wstart += 1;
}
System.out.println();

wstart = start; //resetting working variable

do { 
    double km = start * 1.609;
    wstart += 1;
    System.out.println("miles: " + (wstart) + ", " + 
            "kilometers: " + (km));

} while (start <= end);


//no resetting needed since you already have your iteration variable s here
for (int s=start; s <= end; s++){
    double km = start * 1.609;
    System.out.println("miles: " + (s) + ", " + 
            "kilometers: " + (km));
}
```

Comment: thanks the for the fast resposne, will try this right now!

Answer (score 0):

becose you're updating the value of variable **start** on the 3 loops by writing **start++ ;**

Save the value of start on an another variable, and use this new var before even loop to restaure the old value of start;

Updated code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class brain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the starting mile: ");
        int start2 = keyboard.nextInt();
        int start = start2;
        System.out.print("Enter the ending mile: ");
        int end = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(" A" + start);
        while (start <= end) {
            double km = start * 1.609;
            System.out.println("miles: " + (start) + ", "+ "kilometers: " + (km));
            start += 1;
        }


        start = start2;
        System.out.println();        
        System.out.println(" B" + start);
        do {
            double km = start * 1.609;            
            System.out.println("miles: " + (start) + ", "+ "kilometers: " + (km));
            start += 1;
        } while (start <= end);


        start = start2;
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(" C" + start);
        for (int s = start; s <= end; s++) {            
            double km = s * 1.609;
            System.out.println("miles: " + (s) + ", "+ "kilometers: " + (km));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: trying it out now